# Django - How to create a variable in a view and let it handle template functions

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a Django project and had an issue which I couldn't find on Google or Stackoverflow. So I thought it would be time to ask my very first question.

What I'm trying to do is:
I have a site where users have a dropdown menu, they select and option and click on a play button. this is made with a Django Form. The they should get an popup window (made with only HTML and CSS). So the only thing that has to be done is that a variable is set from 0 to 1 in the view and in my template it then renders the popup. This is the code for that to give you a better idea of what I mean:

```
....
{% if playing_track == 1 %}
    <div class="popup_background">
        <div class="popup_window">
            <p class="popup_text">Route {{ Name_Track }} is gestart</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
....
```

So when playing_track is set to 1 it will display the popup.
Here is the code of the view that needs to handle it:

```
....
playing_track = []

if request.method == 'POST':
    form_run_track = RouteRun(request.POST)
    if form_run_track.is_valid():
        Name_Track = form_run_track.cleaned_data['Name']

        playing_track = 1

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracks/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/')
else:
    form_run_track = RouteRun
....
```

Now to the real question, why doesn't this work?

I sense that it has something to do with the value being set to 1 but when it is reloaded/redirected it is set to 0 again.

I'm really a beginner to Django (have done a lot of HTML/CSS though) and have programmed in C before, maybe I try something that isn't really done this way in Django but more a C like way?

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance!

P.S. I'm using Django 1.5.1 and Python 2.7 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax to render your popup (ie render_to_string) when the user clicks the 'play' link. Or use JQuery to show your popup. Both just require an onClick and some fairly east to write code. Ajax if you need to send data to and receive data from the server JQuery if you have everything loaded from the original template load.

BTW the only way to set a variable in a view (from your template) is to send to via a request. This involves reload the page. Ajax much nicer :)

Comment: At first I didn't really want to use Ajax/Jquery but with your advice I did start to do some research, and it turned out to be the best solution. As you pointed out! I will accept your answer because it fixed the problem for me. Thank you very much!